# Selenium Webdriver for Python traceback errors

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying selenium webdriver for the first time. I've update to Python 3.6 and I reinstalled selenium as well. Trying to open a basic webpage has gone wrong already. Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

It's very basic yet it still isn't working. It's throwing a few errors that are beyond my skill of interpreting. Of course, I tried googling the issue and nothing seemed to help. I'd appreciate any input. These are the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Will Pickard/PycharmProjects/Basics/Webdriver.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 140, in __init__
self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 

Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of  <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x03801170>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 173, in __del__
self.stop()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 145, in stop
    if self.process is None:
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a couple of versions ago,   [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) stopped providing native support for Firefox, and now relies on using an external browser driver for control. Download the available [gecko webdriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and use the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
ff = "/path/to/geckodriver"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=ff)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to install geckodriver ( for gecko browsers like firefox after v47 ) or chromedriver ( for chrome browser). 
Once installed, you should be able to execute code using below mentioned configuration.

You can set DesiredCapabilities as **FIREFOX** and point to driver binary file. You should be able to configure driver with these capabilities and retrieve desired page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
firefox_capabilities['binary'] = '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

Alternatively, if you are not sure that newer version of Firefox is being used, then you can do something like this without setting DesiredCapabilities:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=FirefoxBinary('/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'))
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```