# Selenium Firefox webdriver for python KeyError 'value'

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ubuntu-16.04, selenium-firefoxdriver

I started with the following basic `python` script for using `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

path_bin='/usr/bin/firefox'
path_dr='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
binary=FirefoxBinary(path_bin)
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path_dr,firefox_profile=profile,firefox_binary=binary)
self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
```

Then, I tried executing it twice (first time without `sudo` and second time with `sudo`) as follows:

```
user4@pc-4:~/Scripts$ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2049, in <module>
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path_dr,firefox_profile=profile,firefox_binary=binary)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.service = Service(executable_path, log_path=log_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/service.py", line 44, in __init__
    log_file = open(log_path, "a+") if log_path is not None and log_path != "" else None
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'
user4@pc-4:~/Scripts$ sudo python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2049, in <module>
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path_dr,firefox_profile=profile,firefox_binary=binary)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 155, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 183, in start_session
    self.capabilities = response['value']
KeyError: 'value'
```

So, I have to understand the following:

1. As observed `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'` is being observed when I run the program without a `sudo`. Is that really required?
2. Even though the browser window is opened, in spite of having resolved all the dependencies (I'm using Ubuntu 16.04) like `geckodriver` for Firefox, I'm getting the above error `KeyError: 'value'`. How can I resolve this? Do I have to make any changes in my code to avoid this?

I could use some helpful advice/tips/tweaks to get my program running.

P.S.: Digging into the web to learn on selenium, points to some architecture-specific issues as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44447042/python-3-selenium-keyerror-value-issue-wont-initialize-geckodriver-for-firef) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788251/selenium-webdriver-for-python-traceback-errors) and none of them seems to have been solved and that concerns me. Would chrome be a better option?

Update: The following is the output of `ls -alh`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root       238K Aug 22 17:12 geckodriver.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user4       user       82K  Aug 22 17:08 test.py
```

Comment: From which directory are you launching this test?

Comment: I'm executing in a subdirectory of `home` folder.

Comment: can you do a `ls -alh` and post the output of the same in your question?

Comment: Make sure gecko is at the latest version and so is firefox. A temporary fix to you log file could be by using `self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path_dr,firefox_profile=profile,firefox_binary=binary, log_path='/tmp/gecko.log')

Comment: Just updated the post with your suggestion.

Comment: So, which path should I be using ideally? the `/tmp` one or my pwd?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152524/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-skrowten-hermit).

Answer (score 2):

As you were trying to pass a couple of arguments when invoking **`webdriver.Firefox()`**, we need to consider that **`executable_path`** and **`firefox_binary`** both these arguments takes **`string`** type of arguments. So you need to pass the absolute path of **`geckodriver`** binary to **`executable_path`** and the absolute path of **`firefox`** binary to **`firefox_binary`**. Further you don't need to use `binary=FirefoxBinary(path_bin)`. The following code block works fine on my Windows 8 machine:

> Code is based on **`Python 3.6.1`**

```
from selenium import webdriver

path_bin=r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
path_dr=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe'
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path_dr,firefox_profile=profile,firefox_binary=path_bin)
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
```

As you are on `ubuntu` the following code block must work for you:

```
from selenium import webdriver

path_bin='/usr/bin/firefox'
path_dr='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path_dr,firefox_profile=profile,firefox_binary=path_bin)
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 183, in start_session
self.capabilities = response['value'] 
KeyError: 'value'
```

So I have updated selenium and geckodriver to the latest version. This was the solution in my case.